# Ion-slides doesn’t update dynamic data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, swiper.js

I am using latest version of ionic 4.0.0
I am trying to update content of slider on button click but it doesn’t update the content even array values changed in TypeScript code.
Here us my view code:

```
<ion-slides class="main-slide" pager=true loop="true" #mainSlider [options]="mainSliderOpts">
<ion-slide class="change-display" *ngFor="let product of products;">
    <div class="item-container">
        <div class="strike-title">Strike Price</div>
        <div class="devider"></div>

        <p class="description">
            To at least what price do you think the stock will move from its current price if
            <strong>${{product.price}}</strong>?
        </p>
        <div class="lose" [ngClass]="{ 'profit': product.profit > 0,'lose':   product.profit < 0 }">
            <span *ngIf="product.profit > 0">+</span>{{product.profit}}%
        </div>


        <div class="price-contract">
            PRICE PER CONTRACT: <strong>${{product.contractPrice}}</strong>
        </div>

        <ion-button class="next-btn" (click)=priceSliderChanged() expand="full" color="dark">Change Values</ion-button>

    </div>
</ion-slide>
```

And Here is my typescript code:

```
constructor() {
this.products = [{
        title: 'NFLX',
        price: 313.2,
        prices: [
            297.50,
            295.00,
            292.75,
            290.75
        ],
        profit: 4,
        contractPrice: 400 //defalt price       
    },
    {
        title: 'NFLX 1',
        price: 413.2,
        prices: [
            297.50,
            295.00,
            292.75,
            290.75
        ],
        profit: -6.6,
        contractPrice: 500 //defalt price       
    },
    {
        title: 'NFLX 2',
        price: 213.2,
        prices: [
            297.50,
            295.00,
            292.75,
            290.75
        ],
        profit: -7,
        contractPrice: 300 //defalt price       
    }
]
```

}

priceSliderChanged() {

```
this.mainSlider.getActiveIndex().then((index) => {
    var activeProduct = this.products[index];
    activeProduct.profit = this.randomIntFromInterval(-5, 6);
    activeProduct.contractPrice = this.randomIntFromInterval(350, 460);
    //setTimeout(()=>{
    this.mainSlider.update().then((d: any) => {
        // alert(d);
    });
});
```

}

As you can see contractPrice was changed successfully if I console but not changed in ‘.price-contract’ div.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the case with you but in Ionic 4 beta version I got same problem because `getActiveIndex()` return index from 1 but not from 0. for example if first slide is active it will return 1 instead of 0.

So try to change this code:

```
priceSliderChanged() {
  this.mainSlider.getActiveIndex().then((index) => {
  index-=1; //add this code
  var activeProduct = this.products[index];
  activeProduct.profit = this.randomIntFromInterval(-5, 6);
  activeProduct.contractPrice = this.randomIntFromInterval(350, 460);
 });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the slide data dynamically, it is necessary to do the following:
In your template html

1. add a (change) event listener // make it call a function to call the slides.update(),
2. add a reference to the ion-slides,  #slides

```
 <ion-slides id="slides" #slides pager *ngIf="slideData.length !==0 " (change)="this.updateSlides()">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let s of slideData; let i = index" >
```

In your typescript

3. add the @ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides to reference the component in your typescript.
4. add the function updateSlides()

```
@ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides; //near top
...
updateSlides() {
this.slides.update();
}
```

Now anytime the slideData (array) is updated dynamically  the slides will show correctly.